# Algorithm for creating an id in java

Tags: java

After trying for a few hours now, I cant find a solution for my problem.
I want to generate an id with is generated like this:

- I want my id to be generated from characters from a character array. For the following examples I will use the following array:  `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`.
- I want my id to be generated so that my first 36 id's are the characters from the array and then I want the id to be two characters long and to go through all the possibilities.
  It's kind of like a bruteforce algorithm somewhere.

If you guys have and ideas or questions please let me know.
Im still a programming noob!

(Note that i want the id to be generated by a method that returns a string)

Attempt:

```
public String generate() {
        char[] s = new char[charset.length];
        if (firstIndex == charset.length) {
            firstIndex = 0;
            secondIndex++;
            index++;
        }
        if (secondIndex == charset.length) {
            secondIndex = 0;
            thirdIndex++;
        }
        if(index>charset.length){
            index=charset.length;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            s[i] += charset[secondIndex];
        }

        s[thirdIndex] = charset[firstIndex];

        firstIndex++;
        String result = "";
        for (char c : s) {
            result+=c;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Updatet the question.

Comment: Just to be clear: your array contains 36 characters, so your base can't be 38.

Comment: Yes my bad ^^".

Comment: If the order can be `0-9` first then `a-z`, then you can use `Long.toString(inputNumber, Character.MAX_RADIX)`, where `Character.MAX_RADIX` is `36`. This gives exactly what you're looking for, except that is uses digits first, then letters.

Comment: Thank you it works! I just overthinked my problem. I never knewed this method exitst too.

Comment: By the way, if your goal really is to create an identifier, I suggest you learn about [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) rather than invent your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the order can be `0-9` first then `a-z`, then you can use `Long.toString(inputNumber, Character.MAX_RADIX)`, where `Character.MAX_RADIX` is 36. This gives exactly what you're looking for, except that is uses digits first, then letters."